# Why do "The Gamesters of Triskelion" refer to "thralls" instead of "slaves," or speak of them being "vended," rather than "sold"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, terminology

My favorite episode of the original *Star Trek* series, "[The Gamesters of Triskelion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gamesters_of_Triskelion_(episode))," [is about slavery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239642/did-the-original-star-trek-series-ever-tackle-slavery-as-a-theme-in-one-of-its-e).  However, although the characters do occasionally refer to the situation using words like "slavery," the gamesters' preferred terminology for their prisoners appears to be "thralls."  Moreover, when it comes time for Captain Kirk and his companions to be auctioned off, the gamesters do not refer to them as being "sold," but rather "vended."

These choices of less common synonyms for ordinary words have always struck me as peculiar.  Is there any indication of why this was done?  Was this a conscious choice by the screenwriter Margaret Armen, or perhaps by the producers, to give the episode a particular character?

Comment: Both terms are fairly archaic.

Comment: It certainly gave the situation an exotic flavor. That was my first encounter with the word 'thrall'.

Comment: To vend is technically the offer to sell; many people buy things from vending machines today. But the art is really in the vend. As an example, the payment method involving the act of sale can be separated from the vending, like with an attached automated credit card reader.

Comment: Not so much archaic, but there is a fine distinction between north European thralldom and American slavery. I suspect, however, that the writers chose the term thrall as a perhaps less offensive option. Vend just means sell, so. The 1960s was ethnically charged in the US, the Klan was still quite active, there were still people alive who were actually slaves and there were still some Civil War vets who had died within living memory. (The last CW widow, e.g., died in 2020.) So while the term is certainly exotic, I suspect a more prosaic rationale.

Comment: "Was this a conscious choice by the screenwriter Margaret Armen" heh... I can see her sitting down at her typewriter to type the word "slave" and "thrall" accidentally comes out. Couldn't even blame it on autocorrect.

Comment: @elemtilas: Does that fine distinction hold for slavery in general? Trying to figure out how the restriction to *American* slavery fits into the reasoning, even though it may indeed be the primary connotation for the term "slavery" from an American point of view.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -- As for your question, what does "slavery in general" mean? There are too many variations on the theme. As for my reasoning: the writers were all Americans, the audience were all Americans, the time in which TOS was aired was the 1960s, etc. I think they used a near-synonym simply to avoid any potential problems the word slavery itself might have caused. Basically the entire context for this episode is US history.

Comment: @elemtilas: Well, the episode contains the line "Our race has another name for it. Slavery.", hence the word slavery was not completely avoided. And while the context of the production crew was indeed "US history", the episode itself is arguably most reminiscent of slavery in Ancient Rome with its gladiator fights.

Comment: Perhaps the presence of an African crew member (portrayed by an African-American actress) as one of the parties affected prompted the usage of the softer terminology.  I certainly have so source for this so I'm not offering it as an answer, but it would seem plausible to suggest it.

Comment: @elemtilas I think you may be projecting modern sensibilities back on things.  The attitude of the era was more to doubly condemn people who did horrible things, but tried to cover it in soft language.  The Gamesters circumlocuted around what they were doing to protect their own sensibilities, not the viewer's.

Comment: @Jedediah --- I don't think the 1960s are so far removed that this is an example of projecting "modern sensibilities". Though another thought arises: it could simply be that someone at NBC a/o television censors may have been skittish about the term. Looking back now, I just think "thrall" has Rule of Cool juju that "slave" does not.